# Why does echo "{self::class}" print the valid class name

Tags: php

Let's say this is my class in PHP:

```
Class Test {

  public function __construct() {}

  public function test() {
      $myInfoMsg = "{self::class}: New User created";
      echo $myInfoMsg;
  }

 public function test2() {
      $myInfoMsg = self::class . " : New User created";
      echo $myInfoMsg;

    }
}

$a = new Test();
$a->test();
$a->test1();
```

The output I get for `test()` is as below :

```
{self::class}: New User created
```

And for `test2()`, I get below output:

```
Test: New User created
```

**So why don't `self::class` print the class name in `test()`?**

Comment: *"So why don't self::class expands into an actual class name here?"* -- why would it expand?

Comment: @axiac - edited my question for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. **Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {**.

An alternative to your problem would be:

```
$myInfoMsg = self::class . ": New User {$user['name']} created";
```

Comment: Edited my question a little bit

Comment: @Andy Does my answer not answer your question? **Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {**. And since `{self::class}` does not meet the requirement of the syntax, it is therefore treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

[`self::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) is a keyword (well, two keywords). It is replaced during the compilation phase with a string that contains the full name of the class where it is used.

`"self::class"` is a [double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

`"{self::class}"` is also a double quoted string. Even if `{self::class}` looks similar to a [variable in a double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), it is not a variable and it is not interpreted in any special way. It is exactly the string you see here, no matter in what context it appears.

Only the variables are [identified and replaced](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in double-quote strings.